# Header area not spanning full width in mobile

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am working with Bootstrap, and Flat UI. I am trying to have a header area span full width and the rest of the website fit inside a container thats 940px. The header area looks good in all non-mobile browsers, but when I view it using Safari and Chrome in iOS6 the header is not spanning full width. Can anyone help?

You can view the site [here](http://angelladv.com/client/cellphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have a fixed width of 940 pixels on content area of your website and your top banner is set to only take up 100% of the viewport.  On a cellphone, *100% of the viewport is less than 940 pixels* so you can scroll horizontally to see the rest of the content, but the top banner doesn't stretch further than the original 100% of the viewport.

Instead you may want to try to make your content area more responsive using media queries so that it is more narrow on smaller screens, or you could just give your content area a width of 100%, or you could give your banner a min-width of 940px.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just attached the bootstrap responsive stylesheet and it seems to work alright. I'll have to adjust some of the media queries but overall its much better on mobile than it was before.